# refer super context in es6 javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

how can I refer super context?
Not about referencing super properties or functions.

for example

```
class ParentClass {
    constructor () {}
    aFunction () {}
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor () { super(); }
    aFunction () {
        super.aFunction.apply(***super***, arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a separate super context. You only have on instance, `this`.

Comment: oh. then how can I solve above problem?

Comment: yes. I can pass super context anyway. Isn't really there a proper syntax?

Comment: That is the proper syntax. You want to pass `this` to `super.aFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

The "proper" syntax in a fully-supported ES6 environment would probably be

```
super.aFunction(...arguments);
```

to skip setting a context entirely, however Node does not yet support the spread operator, so you need to explicitly call the function with a context. Even in the case of `super` however, `this` is still the same context, so you'd still do

```
super.aFunction.apply(this, arguments);
```